# How can i resolve this issue: throw new MongooseError('Model.prototype.save() no longer accepts a callback');

Tags: mongodb, express

i am trying to learn backend express.js with mongodb and i am getting this error and can not figure out a solution.

**This is the error message**

```
throw new MongooseError('Model.prototype.save() no longer accepts a callback');
          ^

MongooseError: Model.prototype.save() no longer accepts a callback
```

**Here is the code block that triggers the error**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Author = require('../models/author')

// All Authors Route
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('authors/index')
})

// New Author Route
router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('authors/new', {  author: new Author() })
})

// Create Author Route
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const author = new Author({
        name: req.body.name
    })
     author.save((err, newAuthor) => {
        if(err) {
            res.render('authors/new', {
                author: author,
                errorMessage: 'Error creating author'
            })
        } else {
            res.redirect('authors')
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

I have tried to change to new syntax than .save(), but can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by redoing this part of the code with a .then() and .catch() statement:

```js
// Create Author Route
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const author = new Author({
        name: req.body.name
    })
    author.save().then(item => {
        res.redirect('authors')
        })?.catch(Error => {
            res.render('authors/new', {
                author: author,
                errorMessage: 'Error creating author'
        })
    }
    )
})
```